Why is my up button not navigating to parent activity?
I am building a simple android app and my issue is that when I get to a specific activity the up button does not navigate to the parent activity. My app starts with a MainActivity, from there I can travel to a list of all "vacations" (VacationList) then clicking on a vacation takes me to the VacationActivity. When clicking on the up button while on the VacationActivity the app does nothing when it should be going to the VacationList. I have to use the back button to navigate back. What can I do to fix this?
The up button on all other activities work just fine. I have gone to the AndroidManifest.xml to make changes to the VacationActivity android:parentActivityName property to see if it works by changing the parent activity but the up button does not work no matter what parent activity I use for it. This is what my AndroidManifest.xml looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
            android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.VacationPlanner"
            tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
                android:name=".ui.EditVacationActivity"
                android:parentActivityName=".ui.VacationList"
                android:exported="false" />
        <activity
                android:name=".ui.VacationList"
                android:exported="false"
                android:parentActivityName=".ui.MainActivity" />
        <activity
                android:name=".ui.ExcursionActivity"
                android:exported="false"
                android:parentActivityName=".ui.VacationActivity" />
        <activity
                android:name=".ui.AddVacationActivity"
                android:exported="false"
                android:parentActivityName=".ui.VacationList" />
        <activity
                android:name=".ui.VacationActivity"
                android:exported="false"
                android:parentActivityName=".ui.VacationList" />
        <activity
                android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
                android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

Here is the code for the VacationActivity
package com.rayalva.vacationplanner.ui;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.rayalva.vacationplanner.R;
import com.rayalva.vacationplanner.database.Repository;
import com.rayalva.vacationplanner.entities.Vacation;

public class VacationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Repository repository = new Repository(getApplication());
    int vacationId;
    String title;
    String hotel;
    String startDate;
    String endDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vacation);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        TextView vacationTitle = findViewById(R.id.vacationTitle);
        TextView vacationHotel = findViewById(R.id.vacationHotel);
        TextView vacationStartDate = findViewById(R.id.vacationStartDate);
        TextView vacationEndDate = findViewById(R.id.vacationEndDate);

        if (extras != null) {
            vacationId = extras.getInt("id");
            title = extras.getString("title");
            hotel = extras.getString("hotel");
            startDate = extras.getString("startDate");
            endDate = extras.getString("endDate");
        }

        vacationTitle.setText(title);
        vacationHotel.setText(hotel);
        vacationStartDate.setText(startDate);
        vacationEndDate.setText(endDate);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_vacation, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Vacation vacation = repository.getVacation(vacationId);

        if (id == 16908332) {
            System.out.println("Wht");
        }
        else if (id == R.id.edit) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditVacationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", vacationId);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            intent.putExtra("hotel", hotel);
            intent.putExtra("startDate", startDate);
            intent.putExtra("endDate", endDate);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.delete) {
            repository.delete(vacation);
            Intent intent = new Intent(VacationActivity.this, VacationList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        return true;
    }
}

I placed a breakpoint in the onOptionsItemSelected method and realized that the method is called when the up button is tapped. I guess I don't understand why. All other up buttons on my other activities work perfect despite not overriding the onOptionsItemSelected method. So when I click on the up button nothing happens.
